# Aggregate function calls cannot be nested on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, group-by, count

I have a table:

```
name  | doc  | filter
NAME1 | DOC1 | A1
NAME1 | DOC1 | B1
NAME1 | DOC1 | C1
NAME2 | DOC2 | A1
NAME2 | DOC2 | D1
NAME2 | DOC2 | C1
NAME3 | DOC3 | B1
NAME3 | DOC3 | A1
```

So I create a `SELECT` command:

`SELECT name, doc, array_agg(filter) filter from table group by name, doc`, this return:

```
name  | doc  | filter
NAME1 | DOC1 | {A1,B1,C1}
NAME2 | DOC2 | {A1,D1,C1}
NAME3 | DOC3 | {B1,A1}
```

I am trying to create a `SELECT` command in prior table with the code below:

```
sum(case when array_agg(filter)::char like '%C1%' then 1 else 0 end) as "TOTAL"
```

But I receive the error:

> aggregate function calls cannot be nested

How to solve it? If I want to add one more filter like this:

```
sum(case 
    when array_agg(filter)::char like '%C1%' or array_agg(filter)::char like '%C2%' 
    then 1 else 0 
end) as "TOTAL"`
```

How to do?

Comment: `array_agg(filter)::char like '%C1%'` does not make any sense to me (and if you want to cast an array you should cast it to `::text`). What are you trying to do there? Count the number of values that are `C1` in the `filter` column? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `count(*)  filter (where "filter" = 'C1')` as total?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `filter` is an array of many values that I need to found

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name filter is a field that was created by other table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I update my post.

Comment: So you want an additional column that shows how often the array contains `C1`? Then `count(*) filter (where "filter" = 'C1')` is what you want https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=911169c85d2b4345169527736950132e

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you just want a conditional count:

```
count(*) filter(where "filter" = 'C1') as total
```

This gives you the number of rows in the group where `filter` has value `'C1'`.

If you want to take in account more filter values, then:

```
count(*) filter(where "filter" in ('C1', 'C2')) as total
```

Note that `filter` is a reserved word in Postgres, hence not a good choice for a column name.